# Chrome extension randomly crashing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension randomly crashes for a small portion of users, and I can't replicate it or figure out what's wrong. Users get a notification "[Extension name] has crashed. Click this balloon to reload the extension.", which is the same behavior as when I click End Process on the extension from Chrome task manager, so it seems like the extension is somehow terminated. What are some possible reasons this could be happening? What steps can I take to investigate further? Anecdotally the crash seems to happen often when loading an html file bundled within the extension, but not always.

I got a crash dump from a user but didn't get very far interpreting it. Running it through `minidump_stackwalk` produced this. Is there anyway to further decode this log?

```
Operating system: Mac OS X 10.12.6 16G2136
CPU: amd64
     family 6 model 158 stepping 9
     8 CPUs

GPU: UNKNOWN

Crash reason:  EXC_BREAKPOINT / EXC_I386_BPT
Crash address: 0x10ec219fd
Process uptime: 147598 seconds

Thread 0 (crashed)
 0  Google Chrome Framework + 0x7bfa9fd
    rax = 0x000000000mi0000001   rdx = 0x0000000000000004
    rcx = 0x00007f8a92fc0b04   rbx = 0x0000000000000000
    rsi = 0x0000000000000002   rdi = 0x00007f8a8a80a400
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af52f20   rsp = 0x00007fff5af52f20
     r8 = 0x000000010ec219d0    r9 = 0x0000000000000000
    r10 = 0x0000000000000001   r11 = 0x0000000000000006
    r12 = 0x0000000000000000   r13 = 0x00007f8a92f5eb88
    r14 = 0x000000010ec219d0   r15 = 0x00007f8a8a80a400
    rip = 0x000000010ec219fd
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  Google Chrome Framework + 0x7bfa931
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af52f70   rsp = 0x00007fff5af52f30
    rip = 0x000000010ec21931
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 2  Google Chrome Framework + 0x7bf937b
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af530e0   rsp = 0x00007fff5af52f80
    rip = 0x000000010ec2037b
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 3  Google Chrome Framework + 0x2fc49cf
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af53190   rsp = 0x00007fff5af530f0
    rip = 0x0000000109feb9cf
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 4  Google Chrome Framework + 0x2fd4b9b
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af53260   rsp = 0x00007fff5af531a0
    rip = 0x0000000109ffbb9b
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 5  Google Chrome Framework + 0x2fd493b
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af532b0   rsp = 0x00007fff5af53270
    rip = 0x0000000109ffb93b
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 6  Google Chrome Framework + 0x302ec21
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af532d0   rsp = 0x00007fff5af532c0
    rip = 0x000000010a055c21
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 7  Google Chrome Framework + 0x302942a
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af532e0   rsp = 0x00007fff5af532e0
    rip = 0x000000010a05042a
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 8  Google Chrome Framework + 0x302e4ef
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af53320   rsp = 0x00007fff5af532f0
    rip = 0x000000010a0554ef
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
 9  CoreFoundation + 0xa7a31
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af53330   rsp = 0x00007fff5af53330
    rip = 0x00007fffc47e6a31
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
10  CoreFoundation + 0x8892d
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af53390   rsp = 0x00007fff5af53340
    rip = 0x00007fffc47c792d
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
11  CoreFoundation + 0x87e26
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54080   rsp = 0x00007fff5af533a0
    rip = 0x00007fffc47c6e26
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
12  CoreFoundation + 0x87824
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54110   rsp = 0x00007fff5af54090
    rip = 0x00007fffc47c6824
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
13  Foundation + 0x22ac2
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54150   rsp = 0x00007fff5af54120
    rip = 0x00007fffc61dcac2
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
14  Google Chrome Framework + 0x302f141
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54190   rsp = 0x00007fff5af54160
    rip = 0x000000010a056141
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
15  Google Chrome Framework + 0x302dea2
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af541d0   rsp = 0x00007fff5af541a0
    rip = 0x000000010a054ea2
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
16  Google Chrome Framework + 0x2fd5123
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54200   rsp = 0x00007fff5af541e0
    rip = 0x0000000109ffc123
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
17  Google Chrome Framework + 0x2fab3b3
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54290   rsp = 0x00007fff5af54210
    rip = 0x0000000109fd23b3
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
18  Google Chrome Framework + 0x7c45bcf
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54340   rsp = 0x00007fff5af542a0
    rip = 0x000000010ec6cbcf
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
19  Google Chrome Framework + 0x2a3cb59
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af543b0   rsp = 0x00007fff5af54350
    rip = 0x0000000109a63b59
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
20  Google Chrome Framework + 0x53d7e48
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54700   rsp = 0x00007fff5af543c0
    rip = 0x000000010c3fee48
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
21  Google Chrome Framework + 0x2a3c1a4
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54790   rsp = 0x00007fff5af54710
    rip = 0x0000000109a631a4
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
22  Google Chrome Framework + 0x342b
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af54890   rsp = 0x00007fff5af547a0
    rip = 0x000000010702a42b
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
23  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer) + 0x182f
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af548e0   rsp = 0x00007fff5af548a0
    rip = 0x0000000104cac82f
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
24  libdyld.dylib + 0x5235
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af548f8   rsp = 0x00007fff5af548f0
    rip = 0x00007fffd9fcc235
    Found by: previous frame's frame pointer
25  libdyld.dylib + 0x5235
    rbp = 0x00007fff5af548f8   rsp = 0x00007fff5af548f8
    rip = 0x00007fffd9fcc235
    Found by: stack scanning
```

[UPDATE] We can now reproduce this crash. It happens when we do `chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url:chrome.runtime.getURL("my_extension_page.html"})` several times quickly. The page crashes with error `RESULT_CODE_INVALID_CMDLINE_URL`. Alternatively, if I set this extension page as the newtab page in the manifest and quickly open many tabs, the extension doesn't crash.

Comment: See instructions for adding debugging symbols to chromium crash logs.

Comment: I tried following the "symbolizing minidumps" instructions here http://www.chromium.org/developers/crash-reports#TOC-Symbolizing-Minidumps but it looks like the public crsym repo isn't functional. What instructions are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's the instruction I meant. The repo is working for me.

Comment: @wOxxOm please see updated post on reproducing the error and the error message. I wasn't able to find that error message anywhere in docs. Any ideas?

Comment: Without symbols there's no human-readable call stack so I can't help. And anyway now it looks like a legit bug so you should report it on https://crbug.com.